# Is it possible to add an argument to a custom function added to a filter hook?

Tags: wp-query, filters

Example:  I'm trying to modify an instantiation of WP_Query by using the `posts_orderby` filter like so:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'favorites_orderby');
$new_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'favorites_orderby');
```

the `favorites_orderby()` function is like so:

```
function favorites_orderby($post_in){
    if(is_array($post_in))
        $post_in_str = implode(',', $post_in);
    return $post_in_str;
}
```

`$post_in` is an array that changes based on a previous, separate db query, so I need to be able to pass it into the `favorites_orderby()` function.  Basically it's an array of post IDs that need to get fed to the WP_Query instantiation's `ORDER BY` parameter so that the resulting db request is set like so: `ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 6, 18, 90, 12)`.

Everything works except passing the array of post IDs (`$post_in`) to the `favorites_orderby()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, filters get arguments based on the call to the filter. Basically, filters get their inputs from the apply_filters function call.

If you want to pass in data via another means, use a global variable or wrap the code and the data you want to use in an instance of a class.